# Mismatching keystrokes IntelliJ IDEA after installing Scala plugin

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, keystrokes

I just installed the Scala Plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version:2016.1.3).

So, after the installation, when I type the following symbols, the corresponding symbols get represented inside the class definition of the editor.

" becomes @
; becomes $
, becomes ?
. becomes /
? becomes &

Similarly, a few more characters get printed like this.

**The funny thing is, this happens inside class definitions and inside build.sbt files. (Could happen in other files too). Outside the class definitions, the keystrokes are working fine.**

How can I rectify this?

This happens in .java files and also in Scala files.

I have installed Scala 2.11.8 and SBT 0.13.12. Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Oracle Java Version 8 Update 61.

Comment: Have you checked in File/Settings/Keymap?

Comment: @ZbyszekKr : I checked the keymap, there was not any problem there. I uninstalled and reinstalled the application and the plugins and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question here.

There was no problem with the keymap. I opened another text editor and typed randomly and there was no problem.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the application and the plugins and the problem disappeared. Apparently the problem is unknown. Something might have happened during the installation is what I infer.